# How Does The LGPL Apply To Web and defining distribution?

Tags: licensing, lgpl

If I use an lgpl licensed javascript library, do I have to release my closed source web app that is using it?

I feel like I don't have to, so long as I don't modify the source of the library.

I would like to use an lgpl javascript wysiwyg in a commercial closed source environment.

The closed source web app is never distributed (depending on how the definition of distribution applies to websites), and end users only have access to it.

I find the gpl and lgpl very confusing as they apply to web.

I am also confused what constitutes "distribution".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [one plain English "translation"](http://www.concord.org/license.html), the library remains available under LGPL while your main software can be whatever license you'd like.

Typically with these types of open source programs, you're okay if you just have a "Frobnicator uses the Foo library, available under the Lesser Gnu Public License" statement in your "about" page, along with the LGPL source available in the program somewhere.  I'm not sure I've ever seen just a link to a license, without the actual license text.

One idea might be to just email the developer of the library or the library's mailing list and just ask what you need to do to properly license that library.

And I am not a lawyer, so nothing I've said is necessarily legally true, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, everyone seems to agree on this.

Answer (score 3):

The two major restrictions on the LGPL are modification and dynamic linking.  The LGPL was written with compiled languages in mind, and since JavaScript is not compiled, I do not understand how it can be linked.  As it stands, the LGPL and JavaScript are a poor combination.

Answer (score 2):

That's the point of the **L**GPL: you can use it in your closed source application.

And - being Javascript - the source code of the Library itself is available on the web anyways, you can directly link to it from your "about" page.

Comment: What if the website is accessible only to the company who paid the dev (as in a private portal) ?

Comment: It is important to note, however, that only providing a minified / uglified version is not enough. The full, original (or your modified version of the original,) and unobfuscated source code must be made readily available. I suggest you edit your answer to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

The LGPL allows you to link to the LGPL'd library in a closed-source (commercial) application.  Distribution of the source code for the commercial application is not required.

Comment: what about not making the code (even executable) of the commercial app available at all but using it as a web app or web service?

Answer (score 0):

With LGPL no you don't (need to open the source).